# Flatten DataFrame into a single row with R

Tags: r

Using R I want to reorganize the following mutli-row DataFrame,

```
       1          2       3
A  Apple     Orange   Grape
B    Car      Truck   Plane
C  House  Apartment  Garage
```

into this, single-row DataFrame.

```
     1_A     2_A    3_A  1_B    2_B    3_B    1_C        2_C     3_C
0  Apple  Orange  Grape  Car  Truck  Plane  House  Apartment  Garage
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reshape` solution, which will take care of all the naming and renaming in one step:

```
reshape(cbind(dat, id=1, time=rownames(dat)),
        direction="wide", sep="_", new.row.names=0)[-1]
#    1_A    2_A   3_A 1_B   2_B   3_B   1_C       2_C    3_C
#0 Apple Orange Grape Car Truck Plane House Apartment Garage
```

Comment: The only base R function I never used is `reshape` and it's a pity in all honesty. It's quite a challenge when one would like to abandon `tidyr` and use it instead.

Comment: Nice!  What if I wanted to use Column one instead of the row names? Using the last example I would expect a new Column named 2_Apple with the Value Orange and 3_Apple with the value Grape?

Comment: @coal_canary - `reshape(cbind(dat, id=1), timevar="1", direction="wide", sep="_")[-1]` should do it.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR - it can be a confusing function, but it has a lot of functionality.

Comment: Yes I have to start looking to it as I rarely use `tidyverse` these days. It just has so many confusing arguments.

Comment: @thelatemail Lastly if I wanted to rename with Rowname, Columname or Apple_2  is this possible?

Comment: @coal_canary - sorry, I don't follow that last request.

Comment: @thelatemail  currently the code `reshape(cbind(dat, id=1), timevar="1", direction="wide", sep="_")[-1] `  transforms the column header  to 2_Apple, 3_Apple, 2_Car etc.. is it possible to change the have the columnames read Apple_2, Apple_3, Car_2 ?

Comment: @coal_canary - not directly I don't think. If you save to `out` you can fix it after the fact like: `names(out) <- sub("(.+)_(.+)", "\\2_\\1", names(out))`

Comment: @AnoushiravanR `reshape` is the most underrated function in the whole r. The reason why you need to start using it could be the fact that `reshape` comes out of the box. There is a very good post by Jozef Hajnala, an ardent base-r advocate, [here](https://jozef.io/r001-reshape/). Or a tweet by myself [here](https://twitter.com/EyayawBeze/status/1419277644005318659/photo/1)

Comment: I've also got an attempt to explain some of the basic and more esoteric elements of `reshape` on my github - https://github.com/thelatemail/stats_reshape

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with in `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = !id)

# A tibble: 1 x 9
  `1_A` `1_B` `1_C` `2_A`  `2_B` `2_C`     `3_A` `3_B` `3_C` 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 Apple Car   House Orange Truck Apartment Grape Plane Garage
```

Answer (score 2):

We can `t`ranspose

```
out <- as.data.frame.list(c(t(df1)))
colnames(out) <- paste(colnames(df1)[row(df1)], row.names(df1)[col(df1)], sep="_")
row.names(out) <- "0"
```

-output

```
> out
    1_A    2_A   3_A 1_B   2_B   3_B   1_C       2_C    3_C
0 Apple Orange Grape Car Truck Plane House Apartment Garage
```

---

Or may also do

```
as.data.frame.list(with(as.data.frame(as.table(as.matrix(df1))), 
    setNames(Freq, paste(Var2, Var1, sep="_"))), check.names = FALSE)
    1_A 1_B   1_C    2_A   2_B       2_C   3_A   3_B    3_C
1 Apple Car House Orange Truck Apartment Grape Plane Garage
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`1` = c("Apple", "Car", "House"), `2` = c("Orange", 
"Truck", "Apartment"), `3` = c("Grape", "Plane", "Garage")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C"))
```